# Compute arithmetic-geometric mean without using an epsilon in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, mean

Is it possible to compute arithmetic-geometric mean without using an epsilon in C++?

Here is my code:

```
double agm(double a, double b)
{
    if(a > b)
    {
        a = a + b;
        b = a - b;
        a = a - b;
    }

    double aCurrent(a), bCurrent(b),
        aNext(a), bNext(b);

    while(aCurrent - bCurrent != 0)
    {
        aNext = sqrt(aCurrent*bCurrent);
        bNext = (aCurrent+bCurrent)*0.5;
        aCurrent = aNext;
        bCurrent = bNext;
    }

    return aCurrent;
}

double sqrt(double x)
{
    double res(x * 0.5); 

    do
    {
        res = (res + x/res) * 0.5;
    } while(abs(res*res - x) > 1.0e-9);

    return res;
}
```

And it runs forever.

Actually it is very clear what I was asking. It is just that you never met the problem and maybe lazy to think about it and are saying at once that there is nothing to talk about.

So, here is the solution I was looking for:

Instead of `eps` we can just add the following condition

```
if(aCurrent <= aPrev || bPrev <= bCurrent || bCurrent <= aCurrent )
```

And if the condition is true, then it means that we have computed the arithmetic-geometric mean with the most precision possible on our machine. As you can see there is no `eps`.

Using an `eps` in the question and answer means comparing that we say that two double numbers are equal when the difference between them is less than `eps`.

Please, reconsider opening the question.

Comment: Perhaps if you showed your algorithm – or better code – and explained why you might think you need an epsilon this might be answerable.

Comment: @Richard, I updated the question.

Comment: Swapping doubles by the addition/subtraction trick makes the less accurate and is pretty slow anyway

Comment: What's `sqrt`? Please include a [MCVE].

Comment: @tambre, I updated the question.

Comment: @trafalgarLaww `error: use of undeclared identifier 'sqrt'` and `error: use of undeclared identifier 'abs'`.

Comment: Why have you written your own `sqrt` when there's one built into the `<cmath>` library?

Comment: @Barmar, in order to understand how everything works under hood I am trying to do it myself.

Comment: @trafalgarLaww a proper `sqrt` is *correctly rounded*, not just some arbitrarily bad approximation (for very small `x`, your result is nothing like the square root of `x`). Typically supported by hardware anyway.

Comment: As there is no further mention of `epsilon` in your post, please include in your question to what exactly you are referring to.

Comment: I do not want to use epsilon.

Comment: @harold, there is no problem in that.

Comment: If you say so, but the result could be made more accurate, that will affect the `agm` too obviously.

Comment: @harold, oh. I got your point. Thank you for such an attention. ( :

Comment: No *explicit* limit to the difference between iterations is far from *termination by something else than a lower limit*. And `most precision possible on our machine` different from *best using a single "machine number"*. State *explicitly* what `using an epsilon` shall mean in this question & answers.

Comment: @greybeard, take a look, please.

Comment: (Almost a pity I didn't down-vote your question: I'd take that back following that explication.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can. It suffices to limit the number of iterations to the maximum required for convergence in any case, which should be close to the logarithm of the number of significant bits in the floating-point representation.

The same reasoning holds for the square root. (With a good starting approximation based on the floating-point exponent, i.e. at most a factor 2 away from the exact root, 5 iterations always suffice for doubles).

---

As a side note, avoid using absolute tolerances. Floating-point values can vary in a very wide range. They can be so large that the tolerance is 0 in comparison, or so tiny that they are below the tolerance itself. Prefer relative tolerances, with the extra difficulty that there is no relative tolerance to 0.

Comment: So, could you please tweak the places in my code to make it not execute forever?

Comment: How can I determine the number of iterations required? Will it be enough to do 56 iterations? Since the size of double is 64 bits, from which 1 bit is for sign and 7 bits are for exponent. Or will it be even safer to use 64 iterations?

Comment: @trafalgarLaww: 10 are probably more than enough. You should experiment a little.

Comment: I think without substantiation all of my observations are of no use. ) :

Comment: @trafalgarLaww: ok, you wanted it: http://planetmath.org/convergenceofarithmeticgeometricmean

Comment: So, does it mean that we need only log2(64) iterations?

Comment: @trafalgarLaww: not at all, convergence is superlinear. Spend the effort of some experimentation.

Comment: The convergence is exponent. At least that is what written and proved in the link you provided.

Comment: @trafalgarLaww No, "far more rapidly than any exponential function".

Comment: Thank you. Got it.

Comment: Reconsider opening the question, please.

Comment: @trafalgarLaww: I didn't close that question. Please take care.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible without using an epsilon. Floating point arithmetic is an approximation of real arithmetic, and usually generates roundoff errors. As a result, it's unlikely the two calculation sequences used to compute the AGM will ever converge to exactly the same floating point numbers. So rather than test whether two floating point numbers are equal, you need to test whether they're close enough to each other to consider them effectively equal. And that's done by calculating the difference and testing whether it's really small.

You can either use a hard-coded epsilon value, or calculate it relative to the size of the numbers. The latter tends to be better, because it allows you to work with different number scales. E.g. you shouldn't use the same epsilon to try to calculate the square root of `12345` and `0.000012345`;  `0.01` might be adequate for the large number, but you'd need something like `0.000001` for the small number.

See [What every programmer should know about floating point](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: I tried to read the article and got almost nothing from it. It is very hard to understand what it is about.

Comment: @trafalgarLaww I can imagine that it is harder if English is "more foreign", but pray try to understand at least the concerns addressed. (I take the paper to be about not causing damage by presenting people who *believe* in numbers from computers by not having accuracy match expectations.)

Comment: @greybeard To be fair, it's written in pretty advanced technical language, not really geared to novice programmers.

Comment: Reconsider opening the question, please.